# Google BigQuery API java BigQuery null pointer

Tags: java, google-bigquery

newbie here and I wanted to post the solution to this error. The most related question was asked in 2012 and does not solve this error.

If you use the BigQuery auth here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication

You'll notice a null pointer exception even after double checking your file absolute path. Luckily, I managed to solved this issue by noticing that copy pasting in my copy of a working Gmail API code chunk did not work either.

First, change your

> import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

to

> import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

and loadClientSecrets() to

```
private static GoogleClientSecrets loadClientSecrets() {
    try {
        InputStream in =
                new FileInputStream(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION);
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new InputStreamReader(in));
      return clientSecrets;
    } catch (Exception e)  {
      System.out.println("Could not load clientsecrets.json");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return clientSecrets;
}
```

Comment: this is not the way to make a self answer. clearly describe the issue, they use an answer (not inside the question)